# cron-apt is always unable to connect to network

Tags: networking, cron, apt

I am using cron-apt to keep my Pi up to date. However, since a few weeks, I always get these error messages in the mail, when cron-apt runs:

```
CRON-APT RUN [/etc/cron-apt/config]: Sat Feb 25 04:00:01 CET 2017
CRON-APT SLEEP: 2758, Sat Feb 25 04:45:59 CET 2017
CRON-APT ACTION: 0-update
CRON-APT LINE: /usr/bin/apt-get -o quiet=1 update -o quiet=2
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http: [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/binary-armhf/Packages  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http: [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/binary-armhf/Packages  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http: [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/binary-armhf/Packages  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http: [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http: [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http: [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http: [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http: [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have read that apt might have problems with IPv6, so I did `sudoedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4` and put `Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";` in the file. Now I get these error messages:

```
CRON-APT RUN [/etc/cron-apt/config]: Fri Mar  3 04:00:01 CET 2017
CRON-APT SLEEP: 1528, Fri Mar  3 04:25:29 CET 2017
CRON-APT ACTION: 0-update
CRON-APT LINE: /usr/bin/apt-get -o quiet=1 update -o quiet=2
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/binary-armhf/Packages  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/binary-armhf/Packages  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/binary-armhf/Packages  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/i18n/Translation-en  Unable to connect to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:http:

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` interactively on the command line, everything works fine. What's the problem here?

Comment: *"I always get these error messages..."* -> Just to make sure, do you mean **every single time it runs** or just sometimes/often/occasionally?

Comment: you are right, two days ago it has worked. But it is almost every night